If I have an svg file that is not an image, but a collection of definitions, can I refer to it as an external file?
I have a long list of paths that define the shapes for characters.  128 paths, more or less.  The paths are defined in a <defs> list, and are referred to later, using a <use> element.
I would like to move the definition of paths to a separate file, in the spirit of moving our <style></style> section to a separate file using <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">.  Is such a thing possible with an svg file?
Note it's not an image.  Using <img src=...> doesn't seem appropriate.
. . . 
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <!-- capital_A -->
            <g id="ascii41" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(0.25,2.90)">
                <path
                    d="M 6.144 10.112 L 3.744 2.832 L 1.328 10.112 L 0 10.112 L 3.568 0 L 3.952 0 L 7.52 10.112 L 6.144 10.112 Z M 5.248 6.384 L 5.52 7.392 L 1.808 7.392 L 2.048 6.384 L 5.248 6.384 Z" />
            </g>
            <!-- capital_B -->
            <g id="ascii42" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(0.70,3.00)">
                <path
                    d="M 2.896 9.968 L 0 9.968 L 0 0 L 2.912 0 Q 3.776 0 4.416 0.176 A 3.608 3.608 0 0 1 4.933 0.359 Q 5.238 0.496 5.472 0.68 A 2.133 2.133 0 0 1 5.925 1.162 A 1.937 1.937 0 0 1 6.088 1.456 . . . Z" />
            </g>
            <!-- capital_C -->
            <g id="ascii43" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(0.60,2.95)">
                <path
                    d="M 6.96 1.952 L 5.936 2.544 L 5.792 2.608 L 5.744 2.496 Q 5.776 2.368 5.728 2.256 Q 5.68 2.144 5.552 1.92 A 3.009 3.009 0 0 0 5.285 1.617 Q 5.028 1.364 4.76 1.248 Q 4.352 1.072 3.904 1.072 . . . Z" />
            </g>
            . . . 
        </defs>
    </svg>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="group-of-uses">
        </g>
    </svg>

    <script>
. . . 
                //     Insert the new character. 
                let use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
                use.setAttribute('href', `#ascii${asciiCode.toString(16)}`);
                groupOfUses.insertBefore(use, currentUse);
. . . 



I tried .   Doesn't work.
I can get rectangles and stuff from the svg file referred to by the img tag.   But not defs.

Seems like you're trying to create some sort of text-rendering engine by concatenating multiple SVG paths to display text. In short you won't achieve this with the current markup relying on transforms and absolute coordinates. Sure, you could unravel this  (with an insane effort)  but it's most certainly easier to deploy a library like opentype.js to parse a font file and generate a SVG output.

It does work.   I started out working with font files, but for my purposes, it doesn't work as well.   Mostly, font metrics are not reliable enough to do the fine-tuned markup on the individual characters I am aiming for.
Please do not say "take some other path."   I want to know how one can do the equivalent of the now-deprecated html include.   One possibility is the https://github.com/justinfagnani/html-include-element project.   The jury is still out.

As alternative to Justin his 147 line html-include-element Web Component, I present my 7 line <load-file> Web Component, needs some work if you only want to load partial SVG from external files... you might need 15 lines of code

You can use external <use> references so your letters are stored in an external svg file. See plnkr example. To get a text like rendering (with consistent metrics baseline alignment) you should wrap your paths in a <symbol> as it supports to specify individual viewBoxes. However when loading the external reference you still need to add the glyph viewbox to the parent SVG as they can't autoadjust width/height to match the loaded content.

In fact you could just add the external file name to your existing script href like use.setAttribute('href', sprite.svg#ascii${asciiCode.toString(16)})  or use <img>  tags using fragment identifiers but this would also require some refactoring of your sprite svg.

Yes, @herrstrietzel, I could make a reference to the external definition on each use element.  That would work.   Thanks for the idea.

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman, I like your web component!   Fetch complains about cors though, since I am using the file:// protocol for development.   I developed my own way, while I was waiting for answers to my question.   I'll put it below.

Apparently, the html include was put into the standard, and then taken out.  I suspect because most people are using a server, and if you're using a server you can just insert the file on the server side.  I am working exclusively on the client side.
I made a stupid, dumb solution that works for me.  Not sure if it will have applicability to anyone else.
Here's what goes into your main html file:
<script src="replace_script_with_html_character_definitions.js"></script>

Here's the js file that emits the replace_script_with_html_character_definitions.js file that the main html file refers to:
var fs = require('fs');

var basenameOfHtmlFile = process.argv[2];

var contentsOfHtmlFile = fs.readFileSync(`${basenameOfHtmlFile}.html`, 'utf8');

var contentsOfJsFile = `var elt = document.querySelector('script[src="replace_script_with_html_${basenameOfHtmlFile}.js"]');
elt.outerHTML = \`${contentsOfHtmlFile}\`;
`;

fs.writeFileSync(`replace_script_with_html_${basenameOfHtmlFile}.js`, contentsOfJsFile);


Here's how you invoke the js file:
node replace_script_with_html_generate.js character_definitions

And then your directory has one more file:
-rw-r--r--  1 rickhedin  staff    96K Oct 25 12:46 replace_script_with_html_character_definitions.js
-rw-r--r--  1 rickhedin  staff    96K Oct 25 12:41 character_definitions.html
-rw-r--r--  1 rickhedin  staff   410B Oct 25 12:38 replace_script_with_html_generate.js


